# How can I change the thickness of a doughnut shape without changing the radius?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, borders

I have objects groped together to make a doughnut shape but I want to make the shape thinner. I am using it as a border but my border looks too thick and makes the centre image look small. Is there a way to decrease the thickness of the border objects without affecting the radius?

[image]

Here is the group of objects I want to modify.

I essentially want to do this with it:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If the doughnut is merely a collection of objects, there's no easy solution. You would need to edit the objects directly.

Comment: That's a very skinny doughnut to begin with :-) If it got any thinner it would look like a circular grissini.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With *apologies* and ***thanks*** to **@user3164** - whose incomplete answer I parsed in my comment to it and then ***brazenly*** stole and then expanded on in this answer...

Take your assemblage of objects, and the fill pattern you've made, turn them into a nice straight (but disturbed slightly) line, and make a New Pattern Brush - you needn't even bother with corner pieces as your specific need is for an ellipse - and hey presto - works like a charm!

I used roughen at 1% on a straight rectangle to get the initial fills, then expanded everything (hence the copy of the fill set) to get a nice clean end edge, then made that into the brush.

Looks like this when you then scale the stroke - *exactly* as **@user3164** suggested!

[image]

Oh - and if you separate the body from the salt (or other details) as two brushes - you get additional flexibility...

[image]

And you can apply the TWO separate stroke to ONE single geometric entity using the Appearance Palette - like so:

[image]

Which lets you then save this as a graphic style... and then apply as you'd wish to any simple stroked item you'd like - like this!

[image]

Aaaaand if you're really wanting o finish this out nicely - you then expand your objects and add appropriate end conditions by moving points and adding some judicious curves - sells the results as being more *final*:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: You've given the other "answer" far more credit than it deserves. Your answer is the only real answer here, and it's a really good one if I may say so.

Comment: Wow what you did looks so good! How did you straighten the doughnut out in the first place? Mine is a group of objects at the moment with points all over the place. I imagine it would be easier if it was simplified to only the anchor points around the edges. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Pentax25 - I redrew. Made two rectangles with roughen for base colour & background, drew salt shapes and colour changes over, made those pattern brushes.