# How to make a curly guitar neck

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I want to make a curl out of a guitar neck. Just to give you some idea, I want to know how I can make the neck a bit curled up to the top so that the entire guitar looks like a written "g". The problem is that all those strings and the details are made of many different objects and I cannot make them curly one by one. I would really appreciate it if someone tells me how I can make something like a path and make the neck follow that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two thoughts:

1) - given you already have this much done:
Mesh Warp is your friend.

Don't add too many rows and columns - becomes hard to make smooth.

[image]

So - **DON'T** do this (8 x 9):
[image]

**Do** do this (3 x 3):
[image]

Which as you can see, allows you to melt your vector guitar pretty well.
[image]

Or 2:

Make a pattern brush of your neck - see this question for details - I ***promise*** it would work for you too - super-quickie beneath link to show how that would work / look:
[[How can I change the thickness of a doughnut shape without changing the radius?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121671/how-can-i-change-the-thickness-of-a-doughnut-shape-without-changing-the-radius])

[image]

Comment: Nice. The second option is the most effective and fast.

Comment: Thank you; the pattern brush, works with some minor modifications.